# How to Create Galary xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

When i click on item ( gallery ), it should go to new activity containing some images in grid view with zoom view but don't know how to create xml layout for that ?

Expected output

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJI8o.jpg)

## BeginnerIssuePLZ NEED KIND HELP

PLease Check attached images . .

- mainactivity.xml

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_kitkat_height"
          android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

      <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_lollipop_height"
          android:background="?colorPrimaryDark"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_margin_top">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:text="Inbox"
          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
          android:textColor="@color/md_text" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          android:elevation="4dp"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
          app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

  </FrameLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
      app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
      app:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme" />
  ```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        /**
         * AppCompatActivity, which promises to bring a single consistent ActionBar
         * for all devices starting with API Level 7 and above
         */
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        Toolbar toolbar;
        ActionBar actionBar;
        TextView textView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_layout);

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
            if (navigationView != null) {
                setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
            }
            setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_offers:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_menu:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_gallery:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                                    return true;
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_map:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_contact:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_share:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_settings:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Launching" + menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_help_and_feedback:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                    return true;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }


                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us what have you write to help you

Comment: @FrankN.Stein unexpected answer....

Comment: In facts, it was not an answer. It was a comment. It was legal, before you added your code.

Answer (score 0):

YourGirdview

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
         android:numColumns="auto_fit"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:columnWidth="100dp"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/grid"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

griditem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="9sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomGrid.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
      private Context mContext;
      private final String[] web;
      private final int[] Imageid;

        public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
            mContext = c;
            this.Imageid = Imageid;
            this.web = web;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return web.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View grid;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {

                grid = new View(mContext);
                grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
                TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                textView.setText(web[position]);
                imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
            } else {
                grid = (View) convertView;
            }

            return grid;
        }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView grid;
    String[] web = {
            "Google",
            "Github",
            "Instagram",
            "Facebook",
            "Flickr",
            "Pinterest",
            "Quora",
            "Twitter",
            "Vimeo",
            "WordPress",
            "Youtube",
            "Stumbleupon",
            "SoundCloud",
            "Reddit",
            "Blogger"

    } ;
    int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7,
            R.drawable.image8,
            R.drawable.image9,
            R.drawable.image10,
            R.drawable.image11,
            R.drawable.image12,
            R.drawable.image13,
            R.drawable.image14,
            R.drawable.image15

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Comment: which Main_activity.xml  is used for this example?